How to Append to a Range or Table from Another Range or Table Based on a Criteria
I am trying to create a range/table (it doesn’t matter which) based off of a parent range/table (again, it doesn’t matter which) based on a criteria - for example if Table A has 3 columns, with Name, Date, and Yes/No as contents, I want Table B to include all the rows that have ‘Yes’ in the Yes/No column.
Table A



Name
Date
Yes/No




N1
D1
Yes


N2
D2
No


N3
D3
Yes



Table B



Name
Date




N1
D1


N3
D3



Critically, if the no in the row of N2, I need Table B to then be:
Table B



Name
Date




N1
D1


N3
D3


N2
D2



So far I have tried making use of the FILTER function, but works such that it will insert new entries in between existing rows, making Table B look like the below after the No is changed to a Yes:
Table B



Name
Date




N1
D1


N2
D2


N3
D3



I have also looked into the Vstack function, but it seems to have the same issue of inserting a new entry instead of appending. I looked into VBA as well, but unfortunately I have to use Excel Online so VBA is not available to me.

You can use Power Query:
let
   
    TableB = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableB"]}[Content],

    TableA = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableA"]}[Content],

    NewRows = Table.SelectRows(TableA, each not List.Contains(TableB[Name], [Name])),

    Table = Table.Combine({TableB, NewRows})
    
in
    Table


Does this work on Excel Online? I cannot find a way to make a Power Query.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/use-power-query-in-excel-for-the-web-02652946-de70-48d8-8a34-3db96998ff5a
